# OkHttp not making requests when the URL is an IP address

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm encountering a strange problem with OkHttp on Android. When I make a request with the URL being an IP address it doesn't work. It appears as if the server doesn't exist at all.

I tried doing the same request with Postman, Httpie and various other clients and it worked. However, OkHttp can't seem to make the request. I'm using version 3 of OkHttp by the way.

```
fun getRecentPrice(token: String){
    AndroidNetworking.get("http://192.0.0.1" + URL_RECENT_PRICE)
        .addHeaders(AUTHORIZATION, TOKEN_ + token)
        .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
        .build()
        .getAsJSONObject(object : JSONObjectRequestListener {
            override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject) {
                recentPriceMessage.value = Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), RecentPriceModel::class.java)
            }
            override fun onError(anError: ANError) {
                Log.e("error", anError.errorBody)
            }
        })
}
```

I'm using Android Fast Networking library which uses OkHttp under the hood but I've learnt from my search that it's an OkHttp issue.

**UPDATE**

Using `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the manifest file, inside the application tag seems to solve this issue.

Comment: Just a guess, but did you try with the scheme before the IP address, e.g. http:// before the IP

Comment: @luben yes, I tried that but it also didn't work.

Comment: Do you try it on emulator or real device?

Comment: @SkypeDogg I tried on both but it shouldn't make a difference unless the address is local.

Comment: That was my first though. If IP is local or you just don't have access to it from your phone somehow, it may explain why this works with Postman but not on your phone. I had similar issue (not an issue, just normal behaviour) and I couldn't use my API on phone.

Comment: Just an idea: don't you need a frontslash "/" after your IP adress?

Comment: @SkypeDogg the slash is included in the endpoint concatenated to the base url. The thing is, the server can be reached even in Chrome on the phone but won't work in my app. Also tried connecting to one of our servers using an IP address and it couldn't work. But it did when I used a hostname instead.

Comment: Do you use standard port 80 for this IP? If not you may try to use `192.0.0.1:port_number`

Comment: The server listens on 8000 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This might be an oppinionated comment, but you could try to use Retrofit instead of Fast Android Networking. It is pretty easy to setup and work with and is heavily tested and stable, it's one of the industry standards in fact.

Comment: @Trota Retrofit is a solid library indeed, I have a few projects where I used it, but this issue would persist even if I used it as it is about OkHttp which they both use. I use FAN because, in my opinion, it requires less code.

Answer (score 0):

To use insecure HTTP with OKHttp I found I had to enable CLEARTEXT in the connection specs as its disabled by default.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS, ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT))
            .build()

AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext(),okHttpClient)
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris D. I had seen this kind of solution from days of searching. However, I haven't yet tested if this solves the issue when the URL is an IP address. Will let you know when I test it.

Comment: @GanzaCharlesJunior Did you get the solution to this issue? I have seem to hit the same error. The code is throwing connection error but it seems my server receives no request or nothing. I have not tested it with my named domain yet.

Comment: @DebasishMitra I included `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the manifest file, inside the application tag. It seems to allow insecure connections but I haven't tested for ip address urls again yet. I think it should work though.